# Is "each and every one of you" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is *each and every one of you* singular or plural? I searched this subject and found a similar post [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091111212459AAScdnE) but I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*One* is singular, so *one of you* is singular, so *each and every one of you* is singular.

Comment: What about "any of you"?

Answer (score 4):

It's singular. It's exactly the same as "each one of you."

Answer (score 4):

It's singular, but it does not refer to one person from the group -- it refers to all the people from the group, individually.

Answer (score 2):

Possible alternative answer:

If it were “each *one*” or “every *one*”, then the verb would be conjugated according to *one*, which is singular. In either of these scenarios, it would be “each one *is*” or “every one *is*”,  others have said.

One could also interpret “each and every one” as being plural, with two subjects: “each [*one*]” (*one* is implicit) and “every *one*”. Just as “Billy **and** Susie *are*”, “each [one] **and** every one are.”

This latter interpretation, while grammatically self-consistent, is likely incorrect (and ambiguous!) in most situations, because “each and every” is a compound determiner or pronoun. In this case, as others have said, the subject (“one”) is singular, and the verb should be conjugated accordingly: “each and every one is”.

It is more common in modern English to hear “each one” or “every one” than “each and every one” because choosing one or the other and removing the “and” avoids the grammatical ambiguity described above.

Comment: Most of this answer is fine—the ambiguity mentioned may be far-fetched and exceedingly unlikely to ever occur, but it is there in theory. The claim about one being “more correct” than the other, however, is so off that I had to downvote because of it. If you remove the final paragraph, I’ll happily retract my downvote.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Note that the offending wording has gone away.