# Singular Verb Following "One of . . ."

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

> He is one of the men who do the work.

Could someone explain why it is "do" and not "does" up there? I'm sure this question has been asked before and I've memorized what to do with such sentences. But still I'm confused as to the reason why "do" is correct.

Is the subject up there "men" and not "he"? Why isn't it possible to make "he" the subject?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46311/is-each-and-every-one-of-you-singular-or-plural

Comment: _Here comes one of the men who do the work_ might not sound as awkward. The same principle is involved: He is / here comes {one of the men who do the work}.

Answer (score 0):

Because the subject of 'do' in this sentence *is* 'men'.

Think of it in this way:

Which people do the work? The *men* ***do*** the work.
He is just *one of those men*.

Now, joining them:

> "He is one of the men who *do* the work."

Also, it may be possible to make 'him' the subject, but we'd have to change the sentence.

Comment: I agree. I suppose one could say 'He, among other mean, does the work', but even then some might argue for 'do'.

Comment: Add 'the' to make: "He is the one of the men who does the work."  Now 'one' is no longer part of the men, but singled out to become the antecedent of the verb.

Comment: @WS2 In your construction, *do* would be ungrammatical, though, wouldn't it? It's the same as "He does the work", with an additional part inserted, just to add information.

Comment: @mikhailcazi Yes, you are right, it should be 'does'; it cannot be 'do'. The commas separating the subordinate clause, 'among other men', make that clear.

Comment: @shipr That *does* make sense, but sounds very odd. Also, it doesn't convey the same meaning as the original sentence. :) Perhaps it's more natural to say, "Of the men, he is the one who does the work."

Comment: @mikhailcazi No, it does not have the same meaning as the original sentence; I did not intend that it should.  It does not sound odd to me, however, because I have often said something similar, with a pause (that could of course be set off by commas but not require it).  The way you give does not sound more natural to me, but it *is* more clearly stated.