# Is a verb pattern possible

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct: The teacher told every single one of the pupils rewrite their essays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer indicates correctly a "to" is missing in your formulation.

However, you can get rid of "to" in this recast using the subjunctive mood:

*The teacher **required** that every single one of the pupils **rewrite** their essays.*

*The teacher **required** that every single one of the pupils **should rewrite** their essays.*

"require" and "should require" are subjunctive mood forms here.

The subjunctive mood is much more common after "require," which indicates a strong prescription.

E.g.

> [Health Effects of Low-level Radiation: Joint Hearing ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PCLRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22required%20that%20he%20rewrite%22&dq=%22required%20that%20he%20rewrite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-sUWVeDRD8HbsASH-YDgBQ&redir_esc=y) United
>   States. Congress. House. Committee on Interstate and Foreign Commerce.
>   Subcommittee on Oversight and Investigations - 1979
>
> You're saying that those records came directly from the Federal
>   Government ? Dr. BROWER. This was the AEC veterinarian who was under—
>   his superiors had taken the records and **required that he rewrite**
>   his report

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, it's just missing the word "to":

> The teacher told every single one of the pupils **to** rewrite their essays.

It would also be fine to say:

> The teacher told all the pupils to rewrite their essays.

Comment: Your alternative would be appropriate if the class were told at the same time. The original is much better if they were told individually, as well as emphasising the lack of exceptions.

Comment: 'Every one' takes singular agreement; one assumes it was one essay per pupil.

Answer (score 0):

'Every single one / every single one of the pupils' takes [singular agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46311/is-each-and-every-one-of-you-singular-or-plural). So assuming there was one essay per pupil, and gender of the pupils was unknown or mixed , the correct version is

> The teacher told every single one of the pupils to rewrite their
>   essay.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to know whether a version without "to" is possible.