# "Each/every 5 ml contains..." - which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, determiners, measuring-units, singular-subject-and-verb

Many drug leaflets for liquid dosage forms state how much of the active ingredient is found in 5 ml of the solution.
Would it be correct to state it as "Each 5 ml of the solution contains..." or "Every 5 ml of the solution contain..."?

[Here](https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/product/4566/smpc#gref)'s an example from a British leaflet, and [here](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/fda/fdaDrugXsl.cfm?setid=a83bb037-2e72-42e3-9d59-4ab828f18492&type=display)'s one from an American leaflet. Both use "each", but is it correct to refer to a quantity of 5 ml as a single unit?

Comment: Related to previous threads if not actually a duplicate. $5 is too much to pay / 5 miles is a fair distance to jog / 5g / 5ml is not a large amount. [Medicines.org.UK](https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/product/9475/smpc#gref) has: 'Each 5ml of syrup contains 3400mg sucrose ...' for instance.

Comment: I am struggling to find a dupe for this usage of each/every _together_ with a "quantity" usually considered to be singular in number.

Comment: relevant, but not sure if it a dupe: [Is each and every one of you singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46311/is-each-and-every-one-of-you-singular-or-plural?rq=1)

Comment: In this context either _each_ or _every_ may be used with no change in meaning, and singular verbs (_contains_, not _contain_) work with both. And the size of each individual dose is 5ml, and it's dispensed as a unit. Every unit of anything real has a size. That doesn't make it plural.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent the better part of the morning trying to find duplicates which incorporate both usages, and the only relevant posts that I see do not address the OP on *both* issues..

We have:

[***each/every***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46311/is-each-and-every-one-of-you-singular-or-plural?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and

[***verb agreement with units***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units)

I cannot find an *exact* duplicate on EL&U.
However, both usages *taken on their own*  are normally considered singular  for verb agreement.

> **""Each/Every 5 ml of the solution contain..."**

From MetaEd r.e. *each/every*

> One is singular, so one of you is singular, so each and every one of you is singular.

From ect r.e. *verb agreement with units*

> These constructions are called "mass nouns" (or something comparable). Although they refer to more than one thing (e.g., more than one milliliter of water), they treat these things as a single unit.

It should be:

### ***Each/every 5 ml of the solution contains...***

*Note that post ["verb agreement with units"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units) *still* does not have an accepted answer...

Comment: Verb forms with units is a tricky area. Idiomatic are "Two more miles does not sound too bad."  ... "Two? Many miles still lie ahead!"

Comment: Hmmnn...."_Many miles_ (still ahead)" is not really a unit:  _many_ is just a quantifier for a plural noun.

Comment: _Many pints were downed at the pre-lockdown party. In total, 70 gallons of ale was drunk.'_  Getting closer? I'd say '520 pints were downed!' is acceptable (linguistically).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sounds like a great party...wish I had been there.

Comment: ...and realistically, who would be able to certify the results, given the quantity downed?

Answer (score 0):

It's as correct to use '5ml' as a unit of distribution as it is to use 'a pint' as a unit of distribution of beer.

In the British system a pint consists of 20 fluid ounces so, talking of 5% ABV beer it would be correct to say that "each (or every) pint contains a fluid ounce of alcohol".

'Each' is used to concentrate on individual units of distribution (what each consumer of one unit gets) while 'every' is used to concentrate on the consistency of the manufacturing process.

The Cadbury chocolate company used to advertise it's milk chocolate bar by placing the slogan "A glass and a half into every creamy half pound" above or below a picture of glasses of milk being 'poured' into a chocolate bar. It's the same usage emphasising consistency.

Comment: To me (and I don't know if the fact that English is not my first language drives me to think so) there seems to be a grammatical difference between 5 ml unit and a pint (or a pound), because those two are singular forms, whereas 5 milliliters is plural. Doesn't this make for a grammatical difference?

Comment: @Don_S The point is that 'every 5 ml' is actually short for 'every 5ml _measure_' or 'every 5ml _dose_'. In terms of beer German beer is often sold in 300ml glasses so it would be appropriate to say  "every 300ml of 5% ABV beer contains 15ml of alcohol".

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the otiose "each/every", which serves no purpose because it is impossible that some 5mils of the solution will contain more or less.

It is better to say "**5 millilitres** of syrup contain/contains 3400mg **of** sucrose" (it does not matter which - 5ml can be seen as a single unit or plural millilitres.

The solution is "**One millilitre** of syrup contains 680mg **of** sucrose"

Comment: If the standard dose is 5 ml of syrup, you really shouldn't be saying how much 1 ml contains.

Comment: The term 'each' is not meaningless, it is an implied statement that the liquid is correctly produced and, therefore, consistent in its composition. If the mixing process was not well performed then some 5ml measures would have a higher and some a lower concentration of the active ingredient.

Comment: @BoldBen, the question was about '5 ml of the **solution**' and the concept of a solution implies uniformity.